# how to find out second click on a button

Tags: jquery

i make a jquery function and called it by linking.

```
<a href="javascript:myfunc(ID)"></a>
```

and i want to check in my function that button is second time click or first time

and i want to make different different event on first and second click()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$("#myButton").toggle(function() {
  //click first time 
}, function () {
  //click second time
});
```

You can add as many as you want actually, it just cycles through them,  If you need to bomb out after the second click, just [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) by adding a `$(this).unbind('click')` at the bottom of the last click function, like this:

```
$("#myButton").toggle(function() {
  //click first time 
}, function () {
  //click second time
  $(this).unbind('click'); //without this, it goes back to the first function
                           //on the next click
});
```

Comment: @4thpage - Does it *have* to be in-line? Giving the link an unobtrusive/external handler would be a much better approach if possible.