# one button one function on first click another on second

Tags: jquery

I would like one button to perform two jquery functions. One on the first click then the other on the second click. Here is the code for the two buttons. Is there a way to combine the functions?

```
<input type="button" value="View Page" onclick="ViewPage()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function ViewPage() {
example_animate('-=50%');
$("#mainContent").toggle();
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="View Menu" onclick="ViewMenu()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function ViewMenu() {
example_animate('+=50%');
$("#mainContent").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280397/how-to-find-out-second-click-on-a-button

Answer (score 18):

Try something like this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/)

```
var action = 1;

$("input").on("click", viewSomething);

function viewSomething() {
    if ( action == 1 ) {
        $("body").css("background", "honeydew");
        action = 2;
    } else {
        $("body").css("background", "beige");
        action = 1;
    }
}
```

So in your case it will be

```
function viewSomething() {
    if ( action == 1 ) {
        example_animate('-=50%');
        action = 2;
    } else {
        example_animate('+=50%');
        action = 1;
    }
    $("#mainContent").toggle();
}
```

Comment: I made a simple plugin "Show More/ Show Less" plugin with your code, and its works cool. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `one` method, both will fire only once

```
$("input").one("click", viewSomething);
function viewSomething()
{
    $("body").css("background", "honeydew");
    $("input").one("click", function(){ // on can be used
        $("body").css("background", "beige");
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/1/).

**Update:** If you want to keep the second handler alive then replace `one` with `on` like [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign a name to html element..

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick = 'viewSomething(this)'/>           
<script>
    function viewSomething(e){  

        //First time click
        if(e.name != 'Click'){
           e.name = "Click";
           <!--do whatever..-->
         }//end if

       //When click it again..
       else if(e.name == 'Click'){
           e.name = "Unclick";
           <!--do whatever-->
       }//end else
  }//end function
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store your functions and a counter with `data` to track the index. This is very flexible because you can add as many functions as you like and it'll loop if you keep clicking.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ehatoj/2/edit

```
var funcs = [
  function one() { alert('one'); },
  function two() { alert('two'); },
  function three() { alert('three'); }
];

$('button')
  .data('counter', 0) // begin counter at zero
  .click(function() {
    var counter = $(this).data('counter');
    funcs[ counter ]();
    $(this).data('counter', counter < funcs.length-1 ? ++counter : 0);
  });
```

Comment: Here is what I have now. The call doesn't seem to be correct.  <input type="button" value="View Menu" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var action = 1;
  
  $("mainContent").on("click", viewSomething);
  
  function viewSomething() {
  if ( action == 1 ) {
  example_animate('+=50%');
  action = 2;
  } else {
  example_animate('+=50%');
  action = 1;
  
  }
  $("#mainContent").toggle();
  }
  </script>

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to your button so you know what the button should do, and then test in both functions if the button has this class or not.
Of course you will also need to remove the class in viewMenu(), that would look like this in jQuery v1.8.3 :

```
<input id="toggle-view" type="button" value="View Menu" class="view-page" />

$('#toggle-view').on('click', function() 
{
   var button = $(this);

   if ( button.hasClass('view-page')  ) 
   {
       ViewPage();
       button.removeClass('view-page');   
   } 
   else 
   {
        ViewMenu();
        button.addClass('view-page');
   }
});
```

Comment: This is what I have now. Seems like the call is not being made correctly?

  <input type="button" value="View Menu" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var action = 1;
  
  $("mainContent").on("click", viewSomething);
  
  function viewSomething() {
  if ( action == 1 ) {
  example_animate('+=50%');
  action = 2;
  } else {
  example_animate('+=50%');
  action = 1;
  
  }
  $("#mainContent").toggle();
  }
  </script>